# std::error_condition, values not usable in switch/case constructs

Tags: c++

reduced example

```
#include <system_error>

int main (int, char**)
{
  std::error_code ec;

  switch(ec.default_error_condition().value())
  {
    case std::errc::file_exists: return 1;
    default: return 2;
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

clang result:

```
test.cpp:9:10: error: value of type 'std::errc' is not implicitly convertible to 'int'
    9 |     case std::errc::file_exists: return 1;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried different compiler (GCC, ICC) and only MS cl compiles the code above. At first glance, it looks as if std::errc is an 'normal' enum class, but there is additional template magic ... . I ask myself whether it is intentional that these values should not be used in switch/case.
I could use nested if/else if but a switch/case with fallthrough ability looks much cleaner.

How you work with std::error_code resp. std::error_condition?

Comment: `value()` returns an `int`. `std::errc` is not an int.

Comment: @Raildex ok, but why `value()` returns `int` and not `std::errc`? What is the objective, and how to use it right?

Comment: @Raildex, thx, `switch(static_cast<std::errc>(ec.default_error_condition().value()))` does the job. But ugly style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::error_condition::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_condition/value) returns an `int` not `std::errc` as the value may be an arbitrary `int` passed in to the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_condition/error_condition) or an enum from a different category.

Your code would need to be something like this:

```
auto condition = ec.default_error_condition()
if (condition.category() == std::generic_category())
{
  std::errc err = static_cast<std::errc>(condition.value());
  switch(err)
  {
    case std::errc::file_exists: return 1;
    default: return 2;
  }
}
else
{
  // unexpected error?
}
```

Comment: Yes, `std::error_code::value` is an `int` because it is the native system rc, but I used `std::error_condition::value`! The condition values are the abstract codes which I should use for my program logic (and `std::error_code::values` for logging only) - as far as I understand. The condition values are restricted to - no they ARE - the values from `std::errc` enum class, but, however, `condition.value()` also returns `int`.

Comment: `std::error_condition::value` is the same, it can take errors from many categories so `value` has to be an `int`

Comment: ok, it took some time to understand - at least I think I understand it now. There are (however) multiple condition defining enums, `std::errc`, `std::io_errc`, `std::future_errc`(maybe other) and the category shows me which one is used. And then, yes, `condition::value` must be an `int`...